# Sequence containers - can elements be accessed sequentially only

Tags: c++, c++11

It is stated everywhere that the common property of all sequential containers is that the elements can be accessed sequentially. But we know that `std::array`, `std::vector` and `std::deque` all support fast random access to the elements. `std::list` supports bidirectional iteration, whereas `std::forward_list` supports only unidirectional iteration.

So what does actually "accessed sequentially" means here?

Comment: I think in the context of STL containers, sequence containers are those containers that store internal objects in a linear (sequential) manner. So, `accessed sequentially` means that by a given element inside the container, you can go to the next element of the sequence.

Comment: deque are not guaranteed to store all it's element at contiguous memory locations - so not all of them store in sequential manner

Comment: Yes, the same is true for `std::list`. But no one is talking about contiguous memory here. By sequence, it means that items are stored one after each other in a linear data structure.

Comment: Did you see the [*SequenceContainer* named requirement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/SequenceContainer)? To be fair, the denomination is essentially arbitrary (for instance, exceptions have to be made to make `std::array` a sequence container). As a consequence, it’s not a very useful categorisation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sequential access has little to do with random access or iterators.

For example, `std::set`'s iterator is a bidirectional iterator. You can iterate over elements of a `std::set` just like you would over elements of a `std::vector`.

Sequence containers have a front and a back, and all their elements are between those, in the order you inserted them in. Contrast this with a `std::set`, which conceptually does have a front and a back (minimum and maximum values), but that stores its elements in an order defined by a comparison function. Contrast this also with a `std::unordered_set`, which does not really have a front and a back, and stores its elements in an order determined by a hash function. Finally, contrast this with a `std::stack`, which only has a top (conceptually, a back, but no front).

The only other standard container that has a front and a back and stores its elements in the order you insert them in is `std::queue`. However, you cannot access any arbitrary element in a queue without accessing and removing all the elements in front of it.

So, if I had to give a definition of a sequence container, it would be one with sequential access, meaning access to any of its elements in the order you insert them in, without having to do anything other than iterate over it. As a result, you can sort a sequence container.

Not to be confused with contiguous (or random) access.

That said, it isn't a very useful categorization. More useful categories are those of iterators and of complexity of operations.

Comment: While `std::set` has a bidirectional iterator, its iterator does not guarantee O(1) increment. This isn’t part of the iterator requirement but it’s informally understood to be a somewhat fundamental property that all sequence containers (and *only* sequence containers) happen to possess. I say “happen to” because even though I think it’s a fundamental property it isn’t in any way normative.

Answer (score 3):

A [**Sequence Container**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/SequenceContainer) has the requirement that its elements are stored in a well-defined, determined order, such that a function like `front()` or a reference to its *n<sup>th</sup>* element is meaningful. The fact that *sequential* access is permitted **does not preclude** that *random* access is also allowed.

In contrast, there is no requirement that the elements of an [**Associative Container**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/AssociativeContainer) are stored in any particular order. So, for example, attempting to call `front()` on a `std::set` object is meaningless.